# How to disable the GUI of a Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: user-interface, netbeans-platform

I have a Netbeans application which includes some long periods of time during which it looks unresponsive. I'm adding progress bars via the Progress API, but still I would like to block the GUI while certain tasks are in progress.

Is there a way to do something like a Glass Pane for other Java applications.

I know the IDE has something like that. I sometimes see it on the IDE's own lengthy tasks.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the right place, ProgressUtils has several static methods to run a task on a thread while blocking the UI and optionally showing progress.  See showProgressDialogAndRun and runOffEventDispatchThread (there are others).

Comment: Maybe an example or a link to one will make the answer worthy of marked as such.